# Model Animation works in blender but not in Unity

Tags: animation, import, unity

I made a model in blender gave it an armature and two animations: Walk and Idle. I saved the .blend file directly into my unity assets folder. The animation for walking looks perfect in blender however when I test it in unity it is not right at all. The model moves but in none of the right ways. I tried applying the location rotation and scale and making sure the origin of the model and armature were centered, but none of these solutions worked. Am I missing something?

Comment: If any pictures are needed just let me know and I will upload them.

Comment: Do you have constraints?